# Is it possible to customize iOS Password Autofill Layout (native)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, autofill

I'm currently adopting iOS Autofill feature for my app, and the `default` behavior from iOS is to *add* a yellow overlay in my textfield.

I've been looking in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill) but there is no mention about the possibility/impossibility to customize it.

I've seen several topics to trick it when it comes to web views, but my apps are pure native.

[image]

Comment: what are you try to customize exactly ?

Comment: I want to change the yellow color to something else ( clear would be perfect )

Comment: There isn't anything in the docs, which I am sure you know. I am curious as to whether the yellow is an overlay (a different node) or if it is styling on the field... regardless it sort of makes sense that apple doesn't want you to change the styling. They likely want the user to know that the auto fill is coming from apple not the app itself.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Consistent behavior is what users like, and what works for them

[There is a dark force out there that fights against consistency, and that is the natural tendency of designers and programmers to be creative.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/10/24/user-interface-design-for-programmers/)

Comment: as I understood you need to customize your textfield?

Comment: @HansKapitein The question is not about is it a good idea or not, but is it possible or not.

Comment: @JhonnyTawk Not the textfield. The yellow overlay added by iOS ( for the autofill password feature )

Comment: @CZ54 I worked previously on autofill that wasn't the case. If the problem persists mind sharing code so I can inspect the problem

Comment: @JhonnyTawk you mean you got the autofill ( password generation ) working without the yellow overlay ?

Comment: @CZ54 Yes. that wasn't the case with me (Yellow overlay)